# JVM Compiled using Intel compiler

Tags: java, intel

I did a project before involving program speed optimization for the Intel x86 platform, the performance of the application compiled using `Intel C`++ and using `Intel Performance Primitive (IPP)` is significantly faster than that without IPP.

I wonder if the `JVM` can be compiled for the Intel platform using Intel tools and if it will have significant performance improvement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the machine/native code which is run is generated by the JIT.

For code which is currently written in C or C++ it might be faster, but this code shouldn't be called directly very much.  If you have some critical JNI libraries, it might help.

Comment: Yah I know about JNI, however I was thinking more of JVM that use Intel processor features. So any java app that will run on Intel platform can run better and faster.

Comment: The compile won't change the native code the JIT produces. It can only make the conversion to native code faster.

Comment: I mean for example the Eclipse IDE will perform better on that JVM on Intel CPU...

Comment: Its like compiling `gcc` with `gcc` or the `intel` compiler.  You can speed up how fast the `gcc` compiles code but it won't make the code it produces any faster (or slower or different)

Comment: @xybrek - Peter's mentioned that most of the speed of a Java application itself will be due to the *logic* of the JIT, not what language it was compiled in.  Using a different compiler might speed up the time taken to JIT, but the actual application execution itself would be identical (for non-native methods).  So you'd see a very small overall increase.

Comment: @AndrzejDoyle I see, so there's not much of a performance benefit at all